# Stop Outlook VBA from sending mail within ItemSend() when an error event has occurred

Tags: vba, events, outlook, onerror

Outlook mailitem gets sent when an error occurs during run-time within an ItemSend() event. Placing `Cancel = True` in the code does not even stop this from happening. Is it an inherent VBA flaw?

How would I get around this problem? Any ideas are welcome.

```
Public WithEvents myApp As Outlook.Application

Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub myApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler_myApp_ItemSend
    Cancel = True

    ' Do something erroneous

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler_myApp_ItemSend:
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Error: " Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on both Cancel = True lines, and run your code. Does the code reach either?

Comment: If all this code is in ThisOutlookSession would you edit the question to remove unneeded complications, by removing the first four lines and changing to `Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)`. Would you put in an `Err.Raise` so potential respondents do not introduce mistakes trying to create an error.

Comment: nitro@ thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation why the mail is not sent when closing the inspector.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim objInsp As Inspector

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler_Application_ItemSend

    ' Do something erroneous
    Err.Raise 1

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler_Application_ItemSend:

    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description

    Set objInsp = Item.GetInspector

    ' Look for the mail in the drafts folder
    objInsp.Close olSave

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code. It is mind boggling, because suddenly the code seems to work fine again. I can't be sure but it may perhaps have nothing to do with the problem asked. I will have to wait and see if the problem re-surfaces.

Answer (score -1):

You couldn’t use On Error GoTo to get error event, you could try to use If statement. For example:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next

If Not Left(LCase(Item.Subject), 3) = "re:" And Not Left(LCase(Item.Subject), 3) = "fw:" Then
      prompt$ = "You sending this from " & Item.SendUsingAccount & ". Are you sure you want to send it?"
       If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Sending Account") = vbNo Then
         Cancel = True
       End If
End If

End Sub
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Warn Before Sending Messages to the Wrong Email Address](https://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/prevent-sending-messages-to-wrong-email-address/)

[Application.ItemSend Event (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend)